# Running self-feeding channels in Perl 6

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, raku

I would like to set up a number of threads operating concurrently on a channel, and every one of those threads should be also feeding the channel. One of the threads would decide when to stop. However, this is the closest I have come to doing that:

```
use Algorithm::Evolutionary::Simple;

my $length = 32;
my $supplier = Supplier.new;
my $supply   = $supplier.Supply;
my $channel-one = $supply.Channel;
my $pairs-supply = $supply.batch( elems => 2 );
my $channel-two = $pairs-supply.Channel;

my $single = start {
    react  {
        whenever $channel-one -> $item {
            say "via Channel 1:", max-ones($item);
        }
    }
}

my $pairs = start {
    react  {
        whenever $channel-two -> @pair {
        my @new-chromosome = crossover( @pair[0], @pair[1] );
        say "In Channel 2: ", @new-chromosome;
        $supplier.emit( @new-chromosome[0]);
        $supplier.emit( @new-chromosome[1]);
        }
    }
}

await (^10).map: -> $r {
    start {
    sleep $r/100.0;
        $supplier.emit( random-chromosome($length) );
    }
}

$supplier.done;
```

This stops after a number of emissions. And it's probably not running concurrently anyway. I am using channels instead of supplies and taps because these are not run concurrently, but asynchronously. I *need* supplies because I want to have a seudo-channel that takes the elements in pairs, as it's done above; I haven't seen the way of doing that with pure channels. 
There is no difference above if I change the supply's `emit` to channel's `send`.

So several questions here

1. Are these `react` blocks run in different threads? If not, what would be the way of doing that?
2. Even if they are not, why does it stop even if `$pairs` is emitting to the channel all the time?
3. Could I have "batch" channels created automatically from single-item channels?

*Update 1*: if I eliminate `$supplier.done` from the end, it will just block. If I create a [promise in `whenever`](https://cry.nu/perl6/multithreading-in-perl6/), one for each read, it just blocks and does nothing.

Comment: You can do things like `start react whenever ... { … }` instead of `start { react { whenever ... { … } } }`

Comment: Here's how to get a channel that emits pairwise from another channel: `my Channel $c .= new; $c.send($_) for ^20; $c.close; my Channel $c2 .= new; my $work = start { $c2.send: $_ for $c.List.rotor(2); $c2.close; CATCH { default { $c2.fail($_) } } }; .say for $c2.List; await $work` - check to see if you want :partial on the rotor call, too.

Comment: @BradGilbert there's no difference. Why would that work better?

Comment: @timotimo it's not really what I'm looking for. If I modify it this way  `if ( $count++ < 100 ) {
 $c.send( $count );
    } else {
 $c.close;
    }` so that it keeps feeding the first channel, that feeds the second, it hangs up after the initial 20 numbers. `$count` would be initialized to 0 before that.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/JJ/my-perl6-examples/blob/f01c8c6b270e25eeda4cf69218272ec11e076f3d/concurrent.p6) comes closer to what I want, but still does not cut it. It just drops some pairs and stops after processing the first 40 @timotimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here, stripped down to the minimum necessary

```
my Channel $c .= new;
my Channel $c2 = $c.Supply.batch( elems => 2).Channel;
my Channel $output .= new;
my $count = 0;
$c.send(1) for ^2;

my $more-work = start react whenever $c2 -> @item {
    if ( $count++ < 32 ) {
        $c.send( @item[1]);
    my $sum = sum @item;
    $c.send( $sum );
    $output.send( $sum ); 
    } else {
    $c.close;
    }

}
await $more-work;
loop {
    if my $item = $output.poll {
    $item.say
    } else {
    $output.close;
    }
    if $output.closed  { last };
}
```

A second channel that batches the first channel every two elements is used via the creation of a supply from a channel (`$c.Supply`), batching that supply in batches of two (`batch( elems => 2)`) and turning it back into a channel. A third channel is created for output. 
In order to not exhaust the supply and hang the channel, every second element that is read from the first (and actually, only) channel is put back there. So the second channel that reads in twos is never hanged or waiting for new elements. 
An output channel is created for every new element, and an external counter to finish the operation when it's needed; that output channel is read in a non-blocking way, and closed when there's nothing left to read in the last line. 
To answer precisely to my original questions:

1. Yes, they are, only they are stealing elements from each other.
2. Because the two threads were reading from the same channel. The first one to stumble into an element, reads it.
3. Yes, by turning channels into supplies, batching them and turning them back into channels. Only bear in mind that they are not copies, they will be sharing the self same elements.